Docusign Prefill Nodejs
Source Code of current NodeJS Script to prefill PDF. I have generated this based on the https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/. We have an PDF where want to prefill the PDF & send it to respective audience just to sign it.
#!/usr/bin/env node
 // DocuSign API Request Builder example. Generated: Wed, 29 May 2024 09:49:27 GMT
 // DocuSign Ⓒ 2024. MIT License -- https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
'use strict';
const fse = require('fs-extra')
    , path = require('path')
    , docusign = require('docusign-esign')
    , baseUri = 'https://demo.docusign.net/'
      // Note: the accessToken is for testing and is temporary. It is only good for 8 hours from the time you 
      //       authenticated with API Request Builder. In production, use an OAuth flow to obtain access tokens.
    , accessToken = ''
    , accountId = ''
    , documentDirectory = '.'; // The directory with your documents
// Send the envelope
async function sendDocuSignEnvelope () {
    let templateRole1 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
        email: "demo+rent@gmail.com",  
        name: "pejel",  
        roleName: "Lessor" 
        });
    let templateRole2 = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
        email: "komoca2257@bsomek.com",  
        name: "John Doe",  
        roleName: "Owner" 
        });
    let templateRoles1 = [templateRole1, templateRole2];
    let envelopeDefinition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition.constructFromObject({
        PrefillTabs: [object Object],  
        status: "created",  
        templateId: "1bd33b79-268e-46b2-a947-d8b7580504d6",  
        templateRoles: templateRoles1 
        });
 
    try {
        const dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient();
        dsApi.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        dsApi.setBasePath(baseUri + 'restapi');
        const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApi);
        const envResults = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, 
            {envelopeDefinition: envelopeDefinition});
        console.log (`Create envelope results: ${JSON.stringify(envResults, null, '    ')}`);
        console.log (`The envelopeId is ${envResults.envelopeId}`);
        return envResults.envelopeId;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log (`Error from DocuSign create envelope: ` +
           `${(e && e.response && JSON.stringify(e.response.body))||e}`);
        return false
    }
}
 
/**
 * Create the recipient view URL
 * NOTE: the URL is time limited and must be used within a couple of minutes
 */
async function recipientView (envelopeId) {
    let recipientViewRequest = false;
    if (!recipientViewRequest || !envelopeId) {return}

    try {
        const dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient()
        dsApi.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
        dsApi.setBasePath(baseUri + 'restapi');
        const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApi);
        const viewResults = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(accountId, envelopeId,
            {recipientViewRequest: recipientViewRequest});
        
        console.log (`\nCreate recipient view succeeded.`);
        console.log (`Open the signing ceremony's long URL within 5 minutes: \n${viewResults.url}\n\n`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log (`Error from DocuSign create recipient view: ` +
            `${(e && e.response && JSON.stringify(e.response.body))||e}`);
    }
}
 

// The mainline
/**
 * The mainline can't use "await". So this intermediate function is used.
 */
async function asyncMainline() {
    let envelopeId;
    envelopeId = await sendDocuSignEnvelope();
    await recipientView (envelopeId);
    console.log("Done.\n");
}
asyncMainline()

EnvelopeDefinition:
{
  "templateId": "1bd33b79-268e-46b2-a947-d8b7580504d6",
  "PrefillTabs": {
    "radioGroupTabs": [
      {
        "groupName": "property_usage",
        "radios": [
          {
            "selected": "true",
            "value": "check_residential"
          },
          {
            "selected": "false",
            "value": "check_commercial"
          },
          {
            "selected": "false",
            "value": "check_industrial"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "textTabs": [
      {
        "tabLabel": "created_date",
        "value": "29-05-2024"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "owner_name",
        "value": "John Doe"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "lessor_name",
        "value": "Property Management Company"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "lessor_email",
        "value": "tenants.dxb@ifpm.ae"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "lessor_phone",
        "value": "054 307 0621"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "lessor_emirate_id",
        "value": "Landlord Emirates ID"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "tenant_name",
        "value": "pejel"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "tenant_email",
        "value": "vishalsg42+rent@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "tenant_phone",
        "value": "08879423195"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "tenant_emirate_id",
        "value": "111-1111-11111111-1"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "number_of_co_occupants",
        "value": "1"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "plot_no",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "building_name",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "property_type",
        "value": "undefined"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "location",
        "value": "undefined"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "property_no",
        "value": "undefined"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "property_area",
        "value": "undefined"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "start_date",
        "value": "2024-05-20T06:42:32.532Z"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "end_date",
        "value": "2024-06-19T06:42:32.532Z"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "rent_amount",
        "value": "12000"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "contract_value",
        "value": "12000"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "security_deposit",
        "value": "500"
      },
      {
        "tabLabel": "mode_of_payment",
        "value": "Online & Cheques"
      }
    ]
  },
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "demo+rent@gmail.com",
      "name": "pejel",
      "roleName": "Lessor"
    },
    {
      "email": "komoca2257@bsomek.com",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "roleName": "Owner"
    }
  ],
  "status": "created"
}

I have been trying to prefill the pdf with the above script. It isn't working as expected.
PDF Screenshot
It just sends out the plain PDF instead of prefilling it.

Pre-fill tabs is a feature that is required in some rare situations where you don't want your recipients to be associated with the data that was pre-filled.
Based on your desired behavior screenshot, you do not need this feature, it also does not currently work well when using a template.
The good news is that you don't actually need pre-fill tabs to prefill tabs. I know it's confusing but you can prefill the values of regular tabs just fine.
The code example for this functionality can be found - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-template-tab-values/
And for javascript you will just have this kind of code:
const docusign = require('docusign-esign');

const setTemplateTabValues = async (args) => {

  let envelopeArgs = args.envelopeArgs;
    let envelopeDefinition = makeEnvelope(envelopeArgs);
  let dsApiClient = new docusign.ApiClient();
  dsApiClient.setBasePath(args.basePath);
  dsApiClient.addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + args.accessToken);
  let envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApiClient);
    let results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(args.accountId, {
      envelopeDefinition: envelopeDefinition,
    });
    let envelopeId = results.envelopeId;
  let viewRequest = docusign.RecipientViewRequest.constructFromObject({
    returnUrl: envelopeArgs.dsReturnUrl,
    authenticationMethod: 'none',
    email: envelopeArgs.signerEmail,
    userName: envelopeArgs.signerName,
    clientUserId: envelopeArgs.signerClientId,
  });

  results = await envelopesApi.createRecipientView(args.accountId, envelopeId, {
    recipientViewRequest: viewRequest,
  });

  return { envelopeId: envelopeId, redirectUrl: results.url };
};

function makeEnvelope(args) {

  let envelopeDefinition = docusign.EnvelopeDefinition.constructFromObject({
    templateId: args.templateId,
    status: 'sent',
  });

  let list1 = docusign.List.constructFromObject({
    value: 'green',
    documentId: '1',
    pageNumber: '1',
    tabLabel: 'list',
  });

  // Checkboxes
  let check1 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: 'ckAuthorization',
      selected: 'true',
    });
    let check3 = docusign.Checkbox.constructFromObject({
      tabLabel: 'ckAgreement',
      selected: 'true',
    });
  // The NOde.js SDK has a bug so it cannot create a Number tab at this time.
  // number1 = docusign.Number.constructFromObject({
  //    tabLabel: "numbersOnly", value: '54321'});
  let radioGroup = docusign.RadioGroup.constructFromObject({
    groupName: 'radio1',
        // You only need to provide the radio entry for the entry you're selecting
        radios: [
          docusign.Radio.constructFromObject({ value: 'white', selected: 'true' }),
        ],

  });
  let text = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
    tabLabel: 'text',
    value: 'Jabberwocky!',
  });

  // We can also add a new tab (field) to the ones already in the template:
  let textExtra = docusign.Text.constructFromObject({
    document_id: '1',
    page_number: '1',
    x_position: '280',
    y_position: '172',
    font: 'helvetica',
    font_size: 'size14',
    tab_label: 'added text field',
    height: '23',
    width: '84',
    required: 'false',
    bold: 'true',
    value: args.signerName,
    locked: 'false',
    tab_id: 'name',
  });

  // Pull together the existing and new tabs in a Tabs object:
  let tabs = docusign.Tabs.constructFromObject({
    checkboxTabs: [check1, check3], // numberTabs: [number1],
    radioGroupTabs: [radioGroup],
    textTabs: [text, textExtra],
    listTabs: [list1],
  });
  // Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
  // to the template
  let signer = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    email: args.signerEmail,
    name: args.signerName,
    roleName: 'signer',
    clientUserId: args.signerClientId, // change the signer to be embedded
    tabs: tabs, // Set tab values
  });
  // Create a cc template role.
  let cc = docusign.TemplateRole.constructFromObject({
    email: args.ccEmail,
    name: args.ccName,
    roleName: 'cc',
  });
  // Add the TemplateRole objects to the envelope object
  envelopeDefinition.templateRoles = [signer, cc];
  // Create an envelope custom field to save the our application's
  // data about the envelope
  let customField = docusign.TextCustomField.constructFromObject({
      name: 'app metadata item',
      required: 'false',
      show: 'true', // Yes, include in the CoC
      value: '1234567',
    });
    let customFields = docusign.CustomFields.constructFromObject({
      textCustomFields: [customField],
    });
  envelopeDefinition.customFields = customFields;

  return envelopeDefinition;
}

module.exports = { setTemplateTabValues };

